# Supported recurring payments

Tags: 7, payment-gateways

I would like to activate Recurring Payments in Drupal. Is there a list of supported payment methods?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a Q+A site, so for more targeted, specific questions than this. Anything that doesn't have the potential for a single, objective answer doesn't really suit the format here; same thing for locating off-site documentation/lists/etc, it just doesn't fit with the repository of knowledge we're  building. There are multiple Commerce solutions for various versions of Drupal, so there could be a lot of different answers. Once you're a bit further along in development and have a more concrete, practical question, please post separately with all the details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [Commerce Recurring Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring) module

> Overview
>
> Provides a rules, field and entity based approach to recurring billing
> for Drupal commerce.
>
> Features
>
> Auto-generate new orders based on recurring configuration decoupling
> payment from recurring process and leveraging the payment
> responsibility directly to the payment method.

Also For more details about how you can use this  [Read Recurring payments in Drupal](https://pronovix.com/blog/recurring-payments-drupal)